# Enviar e-mail com conteúdo específico de cada linha retornada do mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, email, phpmailer

Preciso enviar um e-mail avisando o usuário que sua solicitação está vencida, vou no banco e busco todos os registros nessa condição, o problema é que o corpo do e-mail tem que ser o conteúdo de cada linha retornada... Em cada e-mail terá que ir os dados da solicitação do usuário, o usuário só pode receber o e-mail referente a sua solicitação, são dados de entrada, saída, tempo de permanência etc...

Fiz uma parte do código onde ele vai no banco e envia o e-mail para todos, o problema é que o corpo do e-mail está sendo sempre o mesmo.

Como faço para que o PHP vá no banco e mande esses e-mails para uma lista e que o corpo da mensagem seja o conteúdo de cada linha específica para cada usuário ?

**Código que envia para todos com corpo fixo:**

```
  <?php

    $select = "SELECT tb_movto_visitas.*, tb_cad_visitantes.nom_visitante, tb_cad_visitantes.qtd_visitas, tb_cad_motivos.des_motivo, dd_pessoais.nome, dd_pessoais.email  FROM tb_movto_visitas
    LEFT JOIN tb_cad_visitantes ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_visitantes_cod_visitante = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf AND tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf_visitado
    LEFT JOIN tb_cad_motivos ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_motivos_cod_motivo = tb_cad_motivos.cod_motivo
    LEFT JOIN dd_pessoais ON tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = dd_pessoais.cpf2

    WHERE 

    dat_prev_saida < now() and  dat_baixa = 0000-00-00 or
    (dat_prorroga_1 < now() and dat_baixa = 0000-00-00 or dat_prorroga_2 < now() and dat_baixa = 0000-00-00)

    ORDER BY tb_movto_visitas.`sol_visita` DESC";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn , $select);
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($row <> 0) {

    while ($row_solicitacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {


    require_once '/../../lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $smtp_host = '130.100.10.24';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = $smtp_host;
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->From = 'sistemas@abc.com.br'; 
    $mail->FromName = 'Sistema de Visitas';

    $array = explode(",",$row_solicitacao['email']);
    $nb = count($array);
    for ($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++) {
        $mail->AddBCC($array[$i]);
    }


    $email_copia = "";
    $assunto = 'AVISO DE VISITAS VENCIDAS';
    $mensagem  = "Prezado(a) Senhor(a) Diego Santos <br><br>";
    $mensagem .= "De acordo com nosso cadastro de visitantes,<br>";
    $mensagem .= "Para cumprimento do PAD2006, favor  dirigir-se à t <br><br>";
    $mensagem .= "Almeida  <br><br>";
    $mensagem .= "Visitantes: <br>";
    $mensagem .= "Emissão: <br>";
    $mensagem .= "Validade: <br>";

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';  
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $mensagem;
    $mail->AltBody = $mensagem;

    $mail->Send(); 
    }
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Olá, Se bem entendi o SQL já está a funcionar como é pretendido e os endereços dos emails tambem estão ok. O constrangimento está no corpo do email que não está dinamico. É isso?

Comment: Ainda bem. Insira então a resposta e marque como correta :D

Comment: Olá Tiago, é isso mesmo, acabei de conseguir solucionar!! Simplesmente coloquei o envio do e-mail dentro do "for" e para o corpo coloquei a variável vindo do banco 

Ex: 
$mensagem .= "Visitante: ".$row_solicitacao['nom_visitante']." ";
$mensagem .= "Emissão: ".$row_solicitacao['dat_chegada']." ";

Comment: Por favor não adicione RESOLVIDO ou SOLUCIONADO no titulo, o site funciona diferente de fóruns. Visite [tour] para conhecer melhor esse funcionamento.

Comment: Ok, Diegofm, entendido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

A solução foi penas colocar o envio do e-mail dentro laço FOR e inserir as variáveis.

```
<?php

$select = "SELECT tb_movto_visitas.*, tb_cad_visitantes.nom_visitante, tb_cad_visitantes.qtd_visitas, tb_cad_motivos.des_motivo, dd_pessoais.nome, dd_pessoais.email  FROM tb_movto_visitas
LEFT JOIN tb_cad_visitantes ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_visitantes_cod_visitante = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf AND tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf_visitado
LEFT JOIN tb_cad_motivos ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_motivos_cod_motivo = tb_cad_motivos.cod_motivo
LEFT JOIN dd_pessoais ON tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = dd_pessoais.cpf2

WHERE 

dat_prev_saida < now() and  dat_baixa = 0000-00-00 or
(dat_prorroga_1 < now() and dat_baixa = 0000-00-00 or dat_prorroga_2 < now() and dat_baixa = 0000-00-00)

ORDER BY tb_movto_visitas.`sol_visita` DESC";

$query = mysqli_query($conn , $select);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($row <> 0) {

while ($row_solicitacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {


require_once '/../../lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$smtp_host = '130.100.10.24';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = $smtp_host;
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->From = 'sistemas@.com.br'; 
$mail->FromName = 'Sistema de Visitas';

$array = explode(",",$row_solicitacao['email']);
$nb = count($array);
for ($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++) {

$mail->AddBCC($array[$i]);

$email_copia = "";
$assunto = 'AVISO DE VISITAS VENCIDAS';
$mensagem  = "Prezado(a) Senhor(a) ".$row_solicitacao['nom_solicitante']."<br><br>";
$mensagem .= "De acordo com nosso cadastro de visitantes, a(s) pessoa(s)...expirado desde o dia ".$row_solicitacao['dat_prev_saida'].". <br>";
$mensagem .= "Para cumprimento do PAD2006, favor  dirigir-se . <br><br>";
$mensagem .= "Figueiredo. <br><br>";

$mensagem .= "Visitante: ".$row_solicitacao['nom_visitante']." <br>";
$mensagem .= "Emissão: ".$row_solicitacao['dat_chegada']." <br>";
$mensagem .= "Validade: ".$row_solicitacao['dat_prev_saida']." <br>";

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';  
$mail->Subject = $assunto;
$mail->Body = $mensagem;
$mail->AltBody = $mensagem;

$mail->Send(); 
}
}

} 
?>
```